# Kafka Tool can show the actual string instead of the regular hexadecimal format

Tags: apache-kafka

if your messages are UTF-8 encoded strings, Kafka Tool can show the actual string instead of the regular hexadecimal format.

From the [Kafka Tool Documentation](http://www.kafkatool.com/features.html):

> By default Kafka Tool will show your messages and keys in hexadecimal
>   format. However, if your messages are UTF-8 encoded strings, Kafka
>   Tool can show the actual string instead of the regular hexadecimal
>   format.

How do I turn my message into utf8?

Answer (score 62):

The setup is per topic.

Go to:

**Clusters** > **Topics** > select topic > **Properties** > **Content Types** section > change Key and Message from *Byte Array* to ***String***.

[image: Kafka key and message as String in Kafka Tool]

Then you can go to that topic > Partitions > your partition > Retrieve Messages .

do not miss to press **update** as the button is in corner and sometimes not visible if you have a bigger screen

[image]